# Moving a zfs sub file system from one zfs file system to another inside the same pool?

Tags: solaris, zfs, openindiana

On my OpenIndiana system I have the following layout (all are separate ZFS fs within the same pool):

```
rpool
   export
      home
         someuser1
         someuser2
```

I would however prefer to have it this way:

```
rpool
   home
      someuser1
      someuser2
   export
      home -> rpool/home (rpool/home with rpool/export/home as mountpoint)
```

(And yes, I also have set-up automounter to mount the users' homedirs under rpool/home as needed.)

My question; is it possible to move rpool/export/home (with userdirs) to rpool/ (thus creating rpool/home) - or to move rpool/export/home/someuser1 and rpool/export/home/someuser2 to rpool/home ... or must it be done manually with `cp -R`, `mv` or `tar` ?  Everything is within the same pool.

Comment: You can use `zfs send | zfs receive` to transfer ZFS filesystems. But I think its best to leave the system defaults as they are.

Answer (score -1):

You may always use

```
zfs umount poolname
zfs set mountpoint=/some/other poolname
zfs mount poolname
```

but it is definitely not recommended to have home directories directly under `/home`, so better leave it the way it is.

The automounter is used to mount the home directories and this method allows you to move the home directory to a fileserver without problems.